# Serilog Adding Extra Information

Tags: c#, .net-5, serilog

I am using Serilog for .Net 5 web api. It is working fine but adding extra information that is not needed. As I am adding only single information but in log file we have extra information which is not needed. Is there any way to control what should be logged?

[image]

// Log File Text

```
2022-08-19T11:18:48.4609958-07:00 [Information] () Application Starting.##############3
2022-08-19T11:19:25.0417644-07:00 [Information] (LAFitness.SpotReservation.WebAPI.Queries.Query) GraphQL would be calling the following URL: https://localhost:5001/
2022-08-19T11:19:25.0695842-07:00 [Information] (System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GraphQLService.LogicalHandler) Start processing HTTP request "GET" https://localhost:5001/rooms/89
2022-08-19T11:19:25.0714494-07:00 [Information] (System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GraphQLService.ClientHandler) Sending HTTP request "GET" https://localhost:5001/rooms/89
2022-08-19T11:19:27.6939187-07:00 [Information] (System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GraphQLService.ClientHandler) Received HTTP response headers after 2616.3589ms - 200
2022-08-19T11:19:27.6956126-07:00 [Information] (System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GraphQLService.LogicalHandler) End processing HTTP request after 2633.29ms - 200
```

Here is the configuration in appsettings.json file.

//Serilog Configuration

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/applog_.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 30
        }
      }
    ],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.')"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: The outputTemplate controls what the output looks like. Did you try adjusting that?

Comment: @mason this is my output format 
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}". I changed it but still same

Comment: Doesn't look different to me. Which part do you not want in the logs? Be specific.

Comment: I need only line #1, all other lines are extra information i do not need. Please do let me know if you need any more information. TIA

Comment: You see in your configuration how you filtered one source? Do the same, but with that source.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how you could configure this here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration.
So for you concrete example something like this could do it:

```
    "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "LAFitness.SpotReservation": "Warning",
                "System.Net": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                    "path": "Logs/applog_.log",
                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    "rollingInterval": "Day",
                    "retainedFileCountLimit": 30
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, System and Microsoft log Level is set to Information, if you don't want to get those system or Microsoft logs, you should set their minimumLevel to Warning(or even Error):

```
"Serilog": {

"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
  }

},
```

....